# self.response.out.write takes out html tags

Tags: google-app-engine

In google app engine certain html tags are stripped out like tr, table

an example is the following.   The tr is completely stripped out when viewing the html code from a deployed app.

```
self.response.out.write("<html><body><tr><p>hello you1</p></tr></body></html>" )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's your browser wich remove the `tr` because the tr are used with the balise `table`

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.5